# Delete method on Ruby on Rails calls to 'show' mehod instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a little help with Ruby on Rails. I'm running Rails 6.1.4 to learning  how it works, but i have the next problem:

I have two buttons to 'Edit' & 'Show' a friend of my database with this code:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', friend ,class:"btn btn-primary"%></td>

<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_friend_path(friend) ,class:"btn btn-info"%></td>
```

But I cannot add a third one to delete it with this logic, because that button redirects to 'Show' page.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', friend ,class:"btn btn-primary"%></td>
```

Instead of this, someone recommended me to use 'button_to' instruction but i have problems with the styles.

Is any possibillity to use link_to as delete action?

Comment: Any link to the resources or, even better, your code snippets would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`method: :delete` makes difference, because by default if you do not specify it will be `method: :get` (like in show)

```
  <li><%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article), method: :delete %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Show", article_path(@article) } %></li>
```

GL with learning RoR!

Comment: Read [chapter Deleting an Article](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article)

Comment: Thank you for the info, but my order is this:```<ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article),
                    method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></li>
</ul>```